# Angular 4 Test a method which calls another method from the @viewChild

Tags: angular

I have a `getFirstLocation()` method that is calling out to another component which is its `@ViewChild`.

The component is declared like this:

```
export class CreateGroupComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MapComponent) mapcomponent: MapComponent;
  getFirstLocation(location){
    this.mapcomponent.getLocation();
  }
}
```

Test Case(.spc):

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  declarations: [CreateGroupComponent, MapComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
    GroupService,
  ]
})
  .compileComponents();
}));
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateGroupComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('should create getFirstLocation successfully', () => {
  spyOn(timepickerChild, 'getLocation').and.returnValue(true);
  spyOn(component.mapcomponent, 'getLocation').and.returnValue(true);
  component.getFirstLocation('TestData');
  expect(component.getFirstLocation).toBeTruthy();
  expect(timepickerChild.getLocation).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Error:  : could not find an object to spy upon for getLocation()
Thanks for help.

Comment: Please ignore:                                                       
 spyOn(timepickerChild, 'getLocation').and.returnValue(true);